# Versioning of Documents in Couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, versioning, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

We want to add version info in a metadata like information to all of our Documents in Couchbase.

Why?
Since our Entity objects are constantly evolving, we want to achieve the following without breaking our data services:

1. GET all Books of version v1
2. GET all Books of version v2
3. Update all Books of v1 to v2 (via a script)

This way we can support multiple document versions for our various consumers.

**What is the most ideal way to achieve this? How can I store Documents in a way that I can query Couchbase based on versions?**

Comment: Are these versions (v1 and v2) of same Book ?

Comment: @Hemant yes. They are the same Document type. But, different versions with slight variation in fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java dev, so I don't understand all the limitations you're working with in Spring, but have you considered adding a 'version' property to documents?

```
book::0001
{
   "title" : "Moby Dick",
   "version" : 1
}
```

and then

```
book::0002
{
   "title" : "Gone Whalin'",
   "isbn10" : "1492966851",
   "version" : 2
}
```

Comment: Yes we have. But, to retrieve it we might have to configure secondary indexes to optimise it. Is there any way to keep this in the metadata like property and retrieve different versions from, say, book-data-v1 and book-data-v2 automatically?

Comment: Whenever you want to "get all" (e.g. 'GET all Books of version v1') then you'll need a n1ql query anyway. But the only metadata you might be able to use it XATTRS (https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/3.0/concept-docs/xattr.html), but you can't access those with N1QL

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can modify the xattr using Spring Data? We are using Spring Data Reactive Couchbase libs to connect to Couchbase.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of versions in couchbase document is **Optimistic Locking**.
[Plesae have a look here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#version) And one more important thing is we can't modify this version it's handle by couchbase it self.

You can easily handle with spring data couchbase. If you need example for more detail let me know.